# What modifications are possible via a variable of type `const int*&`?

Tags: c++

Can we change the value of `*y` in `void function(const int*& x )` when `y` (i.e `int*y= new int`) is passed as an argument to `function()`?

If anyone could put it in words it would be great. Please refer to the following code for a better comprehension of my question:

```
void DoWork(const int* &n)
{
    *n = *n * 2; // will this change the value of *a? 
}

int main()
{
    int* a= new int;
    DoWork(a);
}
```

I was trying to understand a program where I came across a similar syntax. Have a look at a snippet from that program:

```
void segmentTable(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud,
                  const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& seg_cloud){
  double z_min = -5, z_max = 0;
  
  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
  // Create the segmentation object
  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZRGB> seg;
  // Optional
  seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
  // Mandatory
  seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);

  seg.setInputCloud (cloud);
  seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
  // Project the model inliers
  pcl::ProjectInliers<pcl::PointXYZRGB> proj;
  proj.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  // proj.setIndices (inliers);
  proj.setInputCloud (cloud);
  proj.setModelCoefficients (coefficients);
  proj.filter (*seg_cloud);
  /* Create Convex Hull to segment everything above plane */
  pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cHull;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_hull (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr hull_inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
  cHull.setInputCloud(seg_cloud);
  cHull.reconstruct(*cloud_hull);
  cHull.setDimension (2);
  if (cHull.getDimension () == 2){
    pcl::ExtractPolygonalPrismData<pcl::PointXYZRGB> prism;
    prism.setInputCloud (cloud);
    prism.setInputPlanarHull (cloud_hull);
    prism.setHeightLimits (z_min, z_max);
    prism.setHeightLimits (z_min, z_max);
    prism.segment (*hull_inliers);
  }
  pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB> extract_indices;
  extract_indices.setInputCloud(cloud);
  extract_indices.setIndices(hull_inliers);
  extract_indices.setNegative(true);
  extract_indices.filter(*cloud);
}



void int main(){pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr temp_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2,*temp_cloud);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr seg_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  
  passThroughFilter(temp_cloud);
  
  segmentTable(temp_cloud, seg_cloud);}
```

This code does change the values in temp_cloud and seg_cloud.

Comment: The declaration `const int* &n` says that "`n` is a reference to a pointer to an `int` which is constant". It is the value that `n` is pointing to that is constant, therefore the assignment is invalid. Which [the compiler should have told you](https://godbolt.org/z/88d9eM15j).

Comment: Also note that unless you want to modify the pointer itself (where `n` is pointing) there's almost never a use to pass pointers by reference.

Comment: I think pretty much of how const works in such case is already in depth explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const?rq=1

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can show you a code where it is possible to change the values of *a in such cases.

Comment: @ShivamSiuu If you have a problem with your other code, please post it as a separate question! The details of `const` are quite tricky; it's possible that the answer to the other question would be something entirely different.

Comment: You could introduce a type alias which could perhaps clarify `const int*&` a bit: `using ValueType = const int; using ValuePointer = ValueType*;` which allows you to write `ValueType*&` or `ValuePointer&` instead of `const int*`, i.e. you've got a reference to a pointer that allows you to modify the value of the pointer: `delete n; n = new int;`, you cannot modify the value the pointer points to directly though, e.g. `*n = 2` results in a compiler error.

Comment: The big code blob you added doesn't contain any references to pointers.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo In ''const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud'' Ptr means pointer

Comment: Oh, a pointer in disguise. Well, I don't think that code helps to clarify the question. It was pretty clear without it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo this code does change the values of *temp_cloud, *seg_cloud. I don't know why. This code works

Comment: The two pieces of code you posted are not equivalent. I hope you can understand why from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143344/509868) to the linked question. If not, maybe someone cares enough to explain this in a proper answer.

Comment: The added code is invalid. Most compilers will refuse `void int main()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can upload it on Github or show you the screenshot of it compiling successfully.

Comment: @ShivamSiuu Please read my updated answer

Comment: @anatolyg that link does make sense, but the big blob of code I attached with my question works doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ShivamSiuu Did you read my updated answer? The types in your example and in the added code are not the same

Comment: You have a memory leak in your code. `a` is never deleted. Don't use raw pointers in C++. use `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to change `*n` since it's a `const int`. You need to make it non-`const` for it to work:

```
void DoWork(int*& n)
{
    *n = *n * 2;
}
```

Also note that `*a` is uninitialized so reading it would make the program have undefined behavior. You need to initialize it:

```
int main()
{
    int* a = new int{1};   // *a is now initialized to 1
    DoWork(a);
    delete a;              // and delete
}
```

The global `int a;` that you added isn't involved here. The local `a` in `main` shadows the global `a` in `main` and it's that local `a` that is passed as an argument to `DoWork`.

The code in the added block doesn't do the same thing. In your added code block the value `Ptr` is pointing at is non-`const` so there the value *can* be changed. Consider this:

```
using Ptr = int*;

void foo(const Ptr& p) {     // p = int* const&
    *p *= 2;                 // ok, *p is an int, not a const int
    // p = nullptr;          // error, the pointer is const
}

int main() {
    int* a = new int{1};
    foo(a);
    delete a;
}
```

Comment: Although complete, I don't think we should be teaching modern C++ using raw pointers. It's not C and we have RAII.

Comment: @JHBonarius Indeed, but it'll be trickier to answer in an understandable way without using the same types as OP used.

Comment: This was literally my answer @TedLyngmo This last code block is correct, right? I answered the same thing! It would also change the value of *a, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo does space between Ptr, &  and p matter?

Comment: @ShivamSiuu I wasn't able to understand your answer when you only had the first code snippet in your question. I kind of understand what you mean now but it refers to `DoWork` in "_Therefore, we can change the value of *a inside DoWork()_" which doesn't make sense. You would have to show the type definition for `Ptr` and use that in `DoWork` for your answer to be understandable. No, the space doesn't matter. I just prefer to separate the identifier from the type

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you please add in your answer that your last code block works and it does change the values to which "a" pointer points? I will accept it after that. The conclusion of your answer might be unclear to someone else.

Comment: @ShivamSiuu I was hoping that _`// ok, *p is an int, not a const int`_ would make make that clear. but I added a more verbose text above.